# How do I delay mouse movements in real time windows kernel?

Tags: c++, mouse, delay, smoothing, windows-kernel

You can manipulate the x and y values in real time but how would you delay those values to make the cursor look like it's slow traveling to the next position. Is this even possible?

I've tried messing with using a wait timer in the windows kernel driver but I don't think that's how this is done I can't tell.

Comment: If the mouse position is polled (as opposed to event-driven), then you can just set up a ring buffer sized to the required delay. Edit: nevermind, I misread your question -- thought you wanted to just add input lag, not actually slow the input down.. well, you could use a similar approach where you linearly interpolate the desired position from the current one. More like a sliding window.

Comment: Paddy how would I do the linear interpolate to the desired position in C++ Windows Kernel.

Comment: Well, if you're intercepting and modifying the data in there already, then you have the information you require. It's just about how you manage it. One simple way to introduce a smoothed delay is to take some number of samples and average them. If the mouse stops moving, eventually all the samples will be the same position. As I said, a ring buffer can help with this, and there are tricks whereby you can calculate the average in constant time regardless of the buffer size. This _still_ might not be what you want. It's unclear specifically what "slow traveling" means to you.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest forms of delay is to take samples at regular intervals (polling), and insert them into some kind of machinery that will compute the average of the last `N` samples. This effectively produces a linear interpolation from any position to any other position with a delay of `N / SampleRate`.

To do this efficiently, you can employ a ring buffer. Provided you're storing integer data in there, you can use memoization to avoid averaging the entire buffer every time. Instead, you just keep a running sum until the buffer is full, and then every time you add a new value, you first deduct the previous value (which you're about to replace).

In C++, that might look like this:

```
template<typename ValueType, size_t BufferSize>
struct SummedRingBuffer
{
public:
    void Append(const ValueType& value)
    {
        if (count < BufferSize) [[unlikely]]
        {
            buffer[tail] = value;
            sum += value;
            tail = ++count;
        }
        else [[likely]]
        {
            sum -= buffer[tail];
            buffer[tail] = value;
            sum += value;
            tail = (tail + 1) % BufferSize;
        }
    }

    const ValueType& GetSum() const   { return sum; }
    size_t GetCount() const           { return count; }

private:
    std::array<ValueType, BufferSize> buffer;
    ValueType sum   = {};
    size_t count    = 0;
    size_t tail     = 0;
};
```

And now, for your mouse position, just use two of these buffers:

```
template<typename ValueType, size_t BufferSize>
struct DelayedMousePosition
{
public:
    void SetPos(const ValueType& x, const ValueType& y)
    {
        xvalues.Append(x);
        yvalues.Append(y);
    }

    void GetPos(ValueType& x, ValueType& y)
    {
        if (xvalues.GetCount() > 0)
        {
            x = xvalues.GetSum() / xvalues.GetCount();
            y = yvalues.GetSum() / yvalues.GetCount();
        }
    }
    
private:
    SummedRingBuffer<ValueType, BufferSize> xvalues;
    SummedRingBuffer<ValueType, BufferSize> yvalues;
};
```

You must ensure that your data type is sufficiently large such that any data you push into it will not overflow the sum. So, to be safe you could just use `int64_t` as the type. You should avoid using floating-point types with this method, as the they can cause the sum to drift due to precision errors.

So anyway, let's say you are receiving 60 updates per second, and you want a 500ms smoothing window. Well, that's going to require 30 samples. So you could set up your delay buffer like this:

```
DelayedMousePosition<int64_t, 30> delayedMousePos;
```

Every time you receive a sample, you push it into the buffer with `SetPos`, and then you pull out the smoothed position with `GetPos`. It's that simple! There's no dynamic allocation or any other stuff going on, and it does minimal processing, which is what you want in a driver. Maybe for kernel stuff you'll need to switch out `std::array` for a C-style array. I don't know. But that will be just fine with no other modifications required.

Now, you may be picking up on the fact that I don't do any kernel mode stuff, and I suspect polling is generally not done in most drivers nowadays. At least not for HID devices. So, there may be extra tricks you'll need to do to make this work. But given the lack of specifics in your question, I'd say this is a reasonable a place to start.

Comment: Paddy thank you so much dude for all this help <3 hopefully I can figure it out with what you have given me I appreciate you taking the time to write all of this.